# Use click event for input type image using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am loading page data using ajax. Where I want to run a function on a click for an input,whose type is image and its id starts with 'SubmitVote' followed by some integer. Below is the code, which is nt working.

```
$(function() {
    $('input:image[id^="submitVote"').live('click',function(){
        if(this.id.match(/^submitVote(\d+)$/)){
            var vote=$("#rtngCmb").val();
            var text=$("#userNote").val();
            var alertId=RegExp.$1;

            postVote(alertId, vote, text);
        }
    });
});
```

how it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't modify the markup to include a class, try the following:

```
$('input[type="image"][id^="submitVote"]').live('click', function() {
    if (this.id.match(/^submitVote(\d+)$/)) {
        var vote = $("#rtngCmb").val();
        var text = $("#userNote").val();
        var alertId = RegExp.$1;

        postVote(alertId, vote, text);
    }
});
```

[**Simple example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/6Nkj4/1/)

Also, the reason your did not work the last `]` was missing in your selector.

Answer (score 1):

You best bet is to give all of your images that start with `submitVote` a specific class

```
<input id='submitVote1' type='image' src='image.png' class='submit' />
<input id='submitVote2' type='image' src='image.png' class='submit' />
```

This way you can simply do...

```
$('input.submit').live('click',function(){
        var vote=$("#rtngCmb").val();
        var text=$("#userNote").val();
        var alertId=RegExp.$1;
        postVote(alertId, vote, text);
});
```